# A definite integral involve Logarithmic Functions

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

Here is the integral body:
$$\int_0^m {{x^a}\ln \left( {x + b} \right)dx,a >  - \frac{3}{2},b > 0} $$

Comment: Yup. That's an integral alright.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Surely you can see what happens if you try, say, integration by parts? I don't know if that's the way to go, but when I see a logarithm in the integrand, I think "if I could take its derivative, it would go away!" So I wonder if that would work in this case?

Comment: @DavidH: Perfect! Voting that one up. Now I will smile during breakfast.

Comment: The result is not so simple, except if you can use Lerch function.

Comment: Certainly i tried, but it seems in vain, any good method?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, integration by parts is a good place to start. The $a= -1$ case has to be handled separately (and it's not difficult to show the integral diverges in this case), but otherwise,

$$I(m,a,b)=\int_{0}^{m}x^a\log{\left(x+b\right)}dx=\frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}\log{\left(x+b\right)}\big|_{0}^{m}-\frac{1}{a+1}\int_{0}^{m}\frac{x^{a+1}}{x+b}dx\\
=\frac{m^{a+1}\log{\left(m+b\right)}}{a+1}-\frac{1}{a+1}\int_{0}^{m}\frac{x^{a+1}}{x+b}dx.$$

Since by assumption $b>0$, it's a good candidate for a rescaling argument. Substituting $x=bu$ into the integral that resulted from IBPs abov: $~~dx=b\,du$, $u=\frac{x}{b}$, and so

$$\int_{0}^{m}\frac{x^{a+1}}{x+b}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{m}{b}}\frac{(bu)^{a+1}}{bu+b}(b\,du)\\
=b^{a+1}\int_{0}^{\frac{m}{b}}\frac{u^{a+1}}{u+1}\,du.$$

Simplifications past this this point will depend a great deal upon the individual's opinion about what constitutes 'simpler'.

Comment: For large values of $\dfrac mb$ , the latter integral tends to $-\dfrac\pi{\sin n\pi}$ , where $n=a+1$.

Comment: haha, i find i'v return to my starting point, maybe i failed to express myself properly. In fact, my problem is to work out the integral:$$\int_0^m {\frac{{{x^a}}}{{bx + c}}dx,{\text{ }}where{\text{ }}b,c > 0{\text{ }}and{\text{ }}a \geqslant  - \frac{1}{2}} $$, and i need $m$ for further use.

Comment: @ChaoqingTang Oh, in that case just read my answer in reverse! =p

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int_0^m\frac{x^{n-1}}{x+a}dx=\frac{m^n}{a\cdot n}\cdot~_{_2}F_{_1}\bigg(1,n~;~n+1~;-\frac ma\bigg),$ where $_{_2}F_{_1}$ is the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). For large values of *m*, we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{x+a}dx=-a^n\cdot\pi\cdot\csc(n\pi)$.

Comment: Looks wonderful! Any reference?

Comment: The second identity is derived by first letting $t=\dfrac1{\frac xa+1}$ , then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and employing [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General). As for the first, it is merely a rewriting of what one would obtain by expanding the integrand into its own [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then reversing the order of summation and integration.

Comment: woo, great, thank you!