# A integral about Powers of x and binomials.

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series

Here is the integral
$$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{p - 1}}}}{{x + a}}{{\left( {bx + c} \right)}^q}} dx,where{\text{  }}a,b,c > 0,p,q \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Any upper bounds on $p$ and $q$. The integral diverges if $p-1+q \ge 0$.

Comment: $p-1 \ge -\frac{1}{2}$, $q\ge \frac{1}{2}$ which implies $p-1+q \ge 0$

Comment: thanks for your attention, $$\infty  > p,q \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$$,there is no upper bounds

Comment: Under the proposed conditions on the parameters, this integral is divergent, simply look at the case $p=q=1$. The right conditions are $p>0$ and $p+q<1$.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated above, since the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges, one necessary [convergence condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) is $\Big[(p-1)+q\Big]-1<-1\iff p+q<1$, for $x\to\infty$. For $x\to0$, we have $(p-1)>-1\iff$ $p>0$. So for $q\geqslant\dfrac12$ the integral diverges. But if we were to abandon this latter demand, we'd have

$$I=\frac\pi a\cdot\csc\Big[(p+q)\pi\Big]\cdot\bigg[a^p\cdot(ab-c)^q-\frac{c^{p+q}}{b^p}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma(-q)}\cdot\frac{_{_2}F_{_1}\bigg(1,~p~;~p+q+1~;~\dfrac c{ab}\bigg)}{(p+q)!}\bigg]$$

where $_{_2}F_{_1}$ is the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). This formula is deduced in a similar manner to that from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741993).